# Graph API get Day Note from Microsoft Shift

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

[image: Day Notes on Shifts]In Microsoft Shifts there is the ability to put a Day Note on top for each day.
We want to pull this information using a graph api.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean this api? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-post-shifts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks for replying!
We are trying to get the day note (see this image) and it does not seem to be returned in the API call

Comment: If you wanna query shift details, you may need to use the list api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-shifts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: By the way, I saw your questions before, if you feel some others gave you helpful advice or solve your question, you should accept their post as the answer by click the √ besides their post. It will show your appreciate on their effort and will help others have similar issue to find the answer.